# android - encoding .mp4 video to base64 and decoding from base64 to .mp4

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, decoding, video-encoding

I am developing an application that I have to capture videos using custom camera and saving the video as .mp4 video

I am encoding it using these methods

```
private String encodeVideoTobase64(Uri uri , int index)
{
    String videodata     = "";
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA };

    Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    String videoPath;
    try{
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        videoPath       = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        videoPath = PathsOfVideos.get(index);
    }
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        FileInputStream v_input = new FileInputStream(videoPath);
        ByteArrayOutputStream objByteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] byteBufferString = new byte[8192];
        for (int readNum; (readNum = v_input.read(byteBufferString)) != -1;) 
        {
            objByteArrayOS.write(byteBufferString, 0, readNum);
            System.out.println("read " + readNum + " bytes,");
        }

       videodata = encodeBytes(byteBufferString);//Base64.encodeToString(objByteArrayOS.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return videodata;
}

public static String encodeBytes( byte[] source ) {
    // Since we're not going to have the GZIP encoding turned on,
    // we're not going to have an java.io.IOException thrown, so
    // we should not force the user to have to catch it.
    String encoded = null;
    try {
        encoded = encodeBytes(source, 0, source.length, NO_OPTIONS);
    } catch (java.io.IOException ex) {
        assert false : ex.getMessage();
    }   // end catch
    assert encoded != null;
    return encoded;
} 

 public static String encodeBytes( byte[] source, int off, int len, int options ) throws java.io.IOException {
    byte[] encoded = encodeBytesToBytes( source, off, len, options );

    // Return value according to relevant encoding.
    try {
        return new String( encoded, "US-ASCII");
    }   // end try
    catch (java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException uue) {
        return new String( encoded );
    }   // end catch

}
```

The encoding is done and the encoded video is delivered to the my database successfully.
My Problem is when I am trying to get the video again and trying to decode it to display it to the user. The video doesn't play.

This is how I am trying to decode the video using `decodeFast` method in `MiGBas64` library

```
protected void showInstVideo(int pos) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_video);

//Decode String To Video With mig Base64.
String encodedString = r.getRecipeInstructions().get(pos).getVideoStr();
if (encodedString.compareTo("")!=0) {
    byte[] decodedBytes = MiGBase64.decodeFast(encodedString.getBytes());

    try {
        Date date=new Date();
        String filename="/rec"+ date.toString().replace(" ", "_").replace(":", "_")+".mp4";
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir  = new File(root+"/MyAppName");
        if (!myDir.exists())
            myDir.mkdir();
        File file = new File (myDir, filename);

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        out.write(decodedBytes);
        out.close();

        VideoView instvideo     = (VideoView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.vvdetails);
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(instvideo);
        Uri video = Uri.parse(file.getPath());
        instvideo.setVideoURI(video);

        if (video != null )
        {
            dialog.show();
            instvideo.start();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("Error", e.toString()); 
    }
}
```

}

Now I am very confused. I don't know which method is wrong to use . the encoding methods or the decoding methods ?

Could you please help me to figure out the problem in my code.

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Edit:

```
 public static byte[] encodeBytesToBytes( byte[] source, int off, int len, int options ) throws java.io.IOException {

    if( source == null ){
        throw new NullPointerException( "Cannot serialize a null array." );
    }   // end if: null

    if( off < 0 ){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Cannot have negative offset: " + off );
    }   // end if: off < 0

    if( len < 0 ){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Cannot have length offset: " + len );
    }   // end if: len < 0

    if( off + len > source.length  ){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        String.format( "Cannot have offset of %d and length of %d with array of length %d", off,len,source.length));
    }   // end if: off < 0



    // Compress?
    if( (options & GZIP) != 0 ) {
        java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream  baos  = null;
        java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream gzos  = null;
        MyBase64.OutputStream            b64os = null;

        try {
            // GZip -> Base64 -> ByteArray
            baos = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
            b64os = new MyBase64.OutputStream( baos, ENCODE | options );
            gzos  = new java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream( b64os );

            gzos.write( source, off, len );
            gzos.close();
        }   // end try
        catch( java.io.IOException e ) {
            // Catch it and then throw it immediately so that
            // the finally{} block is called for cleanup.
            throw e;
        }   // end catch
        finally {
            try{ gzos.close();  } catch( Exception e ){}
            try{ b64os.close(); } catch( Exception e ){}
            try{ baos.close();  } catch( Exception e ){}
        }   // end finally

        return baos.toByteArray();
    }   // end if: compress

    // Else, don't compress. Better not to use streams at all then.
    else {
        boolean breakLines = (options & DO_BREAK_LINES) != 0;

        //int    len43   = len * 4 / 3;
        //byte[] outBuff = new byte[   ( len43 )                      // Main 4:3
        //                           + ( (len % 3) > 0 ? 4 : 0 )      // Account for padding
        //                           + (breakLines ? ( len43 / MAX_LINE_LENGTH ) : 0) ]; // New lines
        // Try to determine more precisely how big the array needs to be.
        // If we get it right, we don't have to do an array copy, and
        // we save a bunch of memory.
        int encLen = ( len / 3 ) * 4 + ( len % 3 > 0 ? 4 : 0 ); // Bytes needed for actual encoding
        if( breakLines ){
            encLen += encLen / MAX_LINE_LENGTH; // Plus extra newline characters
        }
        byte[] outBuff = new byte[ encLen ];


        int d = 0;
        int e = 0;
        int len2 = len - 2;
        int lineLength = 0;
        for( ; d < len2; d+=3, e+=4 ) {
            encode3to4( source, d+off, 3, outBuff, e, options );

            lineLength += 4;
            if( breakLines && lineLength >= MAX_LINE_LENGTH )
            {
                outBuff[e+4] = NEW_LINE;
                e++;
                lineLength = 0;
            }   // end if: end of line
        }   // en dfor: each piece of array

        if( d < len ) {
            encode3to4( source, d+off, len - d, outBuff, e, options );
            e += 4;
        }   // end if: some padding needed


        // Only resize array if we didn't guess it right.
        if( e <= outBuff.length - 1 ){
            // If breaking lines and the last byte falls right at
            // the line length (76 bytes per line), there will be
            // one extra byte, and the array will need to be resized.
            // Not too bad of an estimate on array size, I'd say.
            byte[] finalOut = new byte[e];
            System.arraycopy(outBuff,0, finalOut,0,e);
            //System.err.println("Having to resize array from " + outBuff.length + " to " + e );
            return finalOut;
        } else {
            //System.err.println("No need to resize array.");
            return outBuff;
        }

    }   // end else: don't compress

}   // end encodeBytesToBytes

private static byte[] encode3to4( 
byte[] source, int srcOffset, int numSigBytes,
byte[] destination, int destOffset, int options ) {

byte[] ALPHABET = getAlphabet( options ); 


    int inBuff =   ( numSigBytes > 0 ? ((source[ srcOffset     ] << 24) >>>  8) : 0 )
                 | ( numSigBytes > 1 ? ((source[ srcOffset + 1 ] << 24) >>> 16) : 0 )
                 | ( numSigBytes > 2 ? ((source[ srcOffset + 2 ] << 24) >>> 24) : 0 );

    switch( numSigBytes )
    {
        case 3:
            destination[ destOffset     ] = ALPHABET[ (inBuff >>> 18)        ];
            destination[ destOffset + 1 ] = ALPHABET[ (inBuff >>> 12) & 0x3f ];
            destination[ destOffset + 2 ] = ALPHABET[ (inBuff >>>  6) & 0x3f ];
            destination[ destOffset + 3 ] = ALPHABET[ (inBuff       ) & 0x3f ];
            return destination;

        case 2:
            destination[ destOffset     ] = ALPHABET[ (inBuff >>> 18)        ];
            destination[ destOffset + 1 ] = ALPHABET[ (inBuff >>> 12) & 0x3f ];
            destination[ destOffset + 2 ] = ALPHABET[ (inBuff >>>  6) & 0x3f ];
            destination[ destOffset + 3 ] = EQUALS_SIGN;
            return destination;

        case 1:
            destination[ destOffset     ] = ALPHABET[ (inBuff >>> 18)        ];
            destination[ destOffset + 1 ] = ALPHABET[ (inBuff >>> 12) & 0x3f ];
            destination[ destOffset + 2 ] = EQUALS_SIGN;
            destination[ destOffset + 3 ] = EQUALS_SIGN;
            return destination;

        default:
            return destination;
    }   // end switch
}
private final static byte[] getAlphabet( int options ) {
    if ((options & URL_SAFE) == URL_SAFE) {
        return _URL_SAFE_ALPHABET;
    } else if ((options & ORDERED) == ORDERED) {
        return _ORDERED_ALPHABET;
    } else {
        return _STANDARD_ALPHABET;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but i see no base64 encoding done. Can you explain where this happens?

Comment: `return videodata;`. And where/how are you storing this for later use?

Comment: The encoding is done in the two functions named encode bytes. This solution is not mine . I found that on the internet after managing to encode video for almost month or more . I thought it was the right way to encode the video. so if it is wrong what is the right way to encode video . Can you help me please ?

Comment: for your second question the returned video is sent to a web service that saved it in a database. Then in another view I get the video from the Database to display it.

Comment: There is no function `encode bytes`. There is a function encodeVideoToBase64 which calls `encodeBytes` which calls another function `encodeBytes`. The last one then calls `encodeBytesToBytes`. Now my question was: where is the encoding to base64 done?

Comment: Kindly see the edit. I have added the encoding functions

Comment: You posted a very long `encodeBytesToBytes` function but did not tell which part of it you use. Earlier we can see a call `encodeBytes(source, 0, source.length, NO_OPTIONS);`. So please tell the flow. GZIP and b64os are not used is it? Then why post all that code? Post only relevant code please. And tell where the base64 enciding is done in your opinion.

Comment: I have post all this code because it is not my code .. its a library class so I was trying to give you a full overview. GZIP is not used ? yes it is just an integer equals to 2. I think the encoding is done in the function `encode3to4` . If there is another easier way to encode video than using this class ,please guide me.

Comment: But YOU should at least be able to tell the flow! `NO_OPTIONS` is that 'GZIP' ? encode2to4 is no base64 encoding without a proper table.